# JSF2: Re-render all components on page that have a given ID, without absolute paths

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

Is there any way in JSF 2.0/PrimeFaces of **re-rendering all components** (using the PrimeFaces `update="id1 id2..."` attribute or the `<f:ajax render="..."/>` tag) **that have got a given ID**, regardless of whether they are in the same form that contains the button triggering the AJAX re-render or not?

For example, I want my button to re-render all sections on a page that visualize the user's current shopping basket.

Right now, I always have to specify the absolute path to the components that I want to get updated, e.g.

`update=":header:basket :left-sidebar:menu:basket"`

which is rather impractical if the structure of the page changes (besides, I have not been able to figure out the correct path for one of these components). I already tried to implement a custom EL function like this, which traverses the component tree:

`update="{utilBean.findAllComponentsMatchingId('basket')}"`

but at the time that function is evaluated, apparently not the entire component tree has been set up as it doesn't contain the components I am looking for.

How can I deal with this? There certainly must be an easy way of doing AJAX-based updates of sections of the page that are not part of the current `<h:form>`?

Thanks!

Comment: I have re-phrased my question a bit, since I noticed that PrimeFace's `update` attribute is an equivalent to the more common JSF2 `<f:ajax render="...">` tag. I am still looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the definition of your findAllComponentsMatchingId method? This btw doesn't look like a custom EL function call. Additionally "{}" is not an EL expression at all, but I take it that this is an typo.

Perhaps the problem is in the way your findAllComponentsMatchingId works and not that the components are not yet in the tree? It might be useful to look at the `findComponentFor` method in this [RendererUtils](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/ajax4jsf/renderkit/RendererUtils.java.html) class for some inspiration.

Alternatively you could try binding the components you want to be updated to a request scoped or view scoped Map.

E.g. define in faces-context.xml:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>updates</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.HashMap</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Then bind your components to this:

```
<x:someComponent binding="#{updates['foo']}"
```

And then write an EL function that iterates over this `updates` map and returns a space separated list of all components client IDs (`component.getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())`).

Comment: The missing # was indeed a typo, yes.

Comment: My findAllComponentsMatchingId method basically does a tree traversal by first comparing each component's id/client id with the requested id, then recursively iterating over this component's children, etc.. The findComponentFor method you pointed me at seems to be more complex than that. I will have a look at that code tomorrow.

Other than that, I guess I will choose the component-binding approach you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: I finally got it working. The problem was that I was only iterating over the UIComponent's children, and not its children and *facets* (using `getFacetsAndChildren()`). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since (I think) this is determined by the way [`UIComponent.findComponent(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) works, I'm afraid you are out of luck. The closest naming container is taken as a base for the search.

Anyway, inter-form rerenders should not be that common. And naming container structures should not change that often.